# Docker CentOS image NodeJS

Tags: node.js, docker, centos7

I am trying to install NodeJS on a Docker CentOs: 
Below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7.3.1611

ADD https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x /root/
#RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x
RUN bash /root/setup_8.x ;\  
yum -y install nodejs ;\
yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk

#removed the rest of code
```

And I use below to build the container:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

The output is as below:

```
Building test
Step 1/3 : FROM centos:7.3.1611
 ---> 67591570dd29
Step 2/3 : ADD https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x /root/


 ---> 92d4f540a9e8
Removing intermediate container d4cef3605bdd
Step 3/3 : RUN bash /root/setup_8.x ;  yum -y install nodejs ;  yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk
 ---> Running in 2c331b5211c7

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 8.x repo...


## Inspecting system...

+ rpm -q --whatprovides redhat-release || rpm -q --whatprovides centos-release || rpm -q --whatprovides cloudlinux-release || rpm -q --whatprovides sl-release
+ uname -m

## Confirming "el7-x86_64" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodesource-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm'

## Your distribution, identified as "centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support
```

It seems the issue is ‘exec_cmd_nobail "curl -sLf -o /dev/null '${RELEASE_URL}'’ in the setup script returns non-zero output, any hint? The issue was not seen like a week ago when I tried, I guess a change in the Docker Centos image?

=======================

- Resolved! The answers are in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Try `centos:7.2.1511` image?

Comment: Tried different centos7 distributions and nodejs 8,7,6

Comment: Works for me with your Dockerfile. Are you sure this is not a network issue inside your intermediate container ? You should give it a try by attaching it with docker exec and running the curl stuff.

Comment: Not sure, but if it was a network issue, would not "ADD https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x /root/" fail as well?

Comment: Try `RUN curl -SsL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash` instead. Also delete the existing centos images and pull them again

Comment: I think ADD use your host network, download the file and then copy it to the intermediate container, curl run directly inside your intermediate container. Not sure tho. `docker run --rm -it 92d4f540a9e8 bash` should attach you to the last succeeded step. From there you could try to manually run the next steps and debug.

Comment: Thanks all! "docker system prune -a -f" worked for me

Answer (score -1):

This is how I made it work after trying lots of different ways:

```
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
RUN source $HOME/.bashrc && nvm install 12.14.1

RUN ln -s $HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node /usr/bin/node
RUN ln -s $HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
```